# a name for kind of a trip. (Star Trip)

Tags: slang

How do they call a trip that you sleep in one place and each day you go to another direction?
Is there a name or a slang for this?
I want to search for information about that kind of trip and I don't know what should I write in the search engine.
(in Hebrew we call it a 'star trip')

Comment: Are you talking about a road trip?

Comment: @KevinWorkman From OP's description of "sleeping in one place and each day going in a new direction", along with bling the trip a "star trip" (as in a shape with a fixed center and lines radiating in all directions), in guessing he means you make camp or get a hotel or whatever in a single, central, location, and each day when you get up you walk towards a new, unexplored, point of the compass. That's a guess, and it's weakened by the fact hats I've never heard of such a trip structure. Though I make a habit of it exploring my city....

Comment: @DanBron , Yes you're right, I mean to sleep in one place for deveral days, not a road trip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to do a series of [day trips](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/day+trip) [TFD]

> a journey made to and from a place within one day

At the end of each day, you'd return to your chosen [home base](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home%20base) [MWD] (not necessarily your home)

> the place in which someone or something lives or operates

For examples, you could google "day trips in *your destination*"

Comment: But it sounds more like just one of the corner of the star... if you know what i mean :) isn't there another definition for this? maybe i didn't emphasize that it is a trip of several days.

Comment: I want to search for potential places that fit for day trips each day, not just one day trip.

Comment: For example, searching for "best day trips from Paris" returns day trips to Versailles, Giverny, etc. while staying in Paris.

Comment: thanks! yet i think the English Academy should consider adding the _star trip_ to the lexicon :)